# Representation theorem linear programming

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

What I have read is:

> The General Representation Theorem states that every point in a convex set can be represented as a convex combination of extreme points, plus a nonnegative linear combination of extreme directions.

It says general form. But I think that the following should also be true:

> Every point in a convex set can be represented as a convex combination of extreme points, plus a nonnegative multiple of any extreme direction.

Is this true? Is there a very counterexample?

Comment: Given a nonnegative combination of extreme directions, can you write it as nonnegative multiple of a single extreme direction?

Comment: I guess every linear combination of directions of unboundedness is a direction of unboundedness!

Comment: Consider the first quadrant (the nonnegative orthant) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What are the extreme points and extreme directions?

Comment: Extreme point is (0,0) and extreme directions are (x,y) with x,y>0

Comment: Yes, $(0,0)$ is the only extreme point, but there are only two extreme directions.

Comment: Why just two, and not infinite like I mentioned?

Comment: Isn't extreme direction same as direction of unboundedness?

Comment: No, only $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are extreme directions here.  Any other direction can be expressed as a combination of those two.